# Read stdin character by character C++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, character, stdin

in my Windows Console application I have to read characters from stdin without waiting for newline (press Entrer).

I tried out get, getchar and tons of other solutions, but this question still open for me. Can anybody help me, how I can reach it?

Answer (score 1):

It's `_getch` (or `_getche` if you want character echoing). Include `<conio.h>`.